# WooPayments Multi-Currency with AJAX

Tags: ajax, woocommerce

I'm using WooPayments Multi-Currency to change the currency options, it works great except for when I load products with AJAX as they are still showing in my default currency.

What can I do to get these to appear in the selected currency?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this documaintation step by step: https://woocommerce.com/document/woopayments/currencies/multi-currency-setup/#switching-block

Comment: Nothing there covers loading products via AJAX, everything is working correctly when they are loaded normally it is only when loading via AJAX it is showing the default currency